# Azure AD: Roles claims missing in access token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

For my application, I want users to be able to sign in with their Azure Account (Single Sign On). I also need an access token to access the secured backend.
So I can get both, the `id_token` and the `access_token`, with a request to this url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT_ID/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token+token&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&state=SOME_STATE&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI&scope=openid profile&resource=MY_CLIENT_ID&nonce=SOME_NONCE
```

This basically works, but I also want to have the roles in the access token (and in the id token), but the **roles are not included** in the tokens I receive.

When I use this Url to only get an `id_token`, **the role claims are included**:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT_ID/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&state=SOME_STATE&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI&scope=openid profile&nonce=SOME_NONCE
```

The difference is I request only the `id_token` and not the `token` and I leave out the `resource` parameter.

My questions are: Why are the role claims not included in the tokens of the first request? What are my options to get `id_token` and the `access_token` with the roles claims?

edit:
This is how the approles are defined in the app's manifest:

```
{
  "appId": "MY_CLIENT_ID",
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Admin",
      "id": "c200e304-fff3-49f1-a4df-e406741ea690",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Bla bla",
      "value": "admin"
    },
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Reader",
      "id": "c534f351-b343-48d0-9dd7-ecb4c5cb402d",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Bla bla",
      "value": "reader"
    }
  ],
  "availableToOtherTenants": false,
  ...
}
```

Comment: I've never seen the `token` parameter used actually. Have you tried to do the same thing with authorization code grant flow? I.e. `response_type=id_token+code`, and then exchanging the code for an access token.

Comment: I will give it a try. So do you think this is a bug then?

Comment: Not sure, it seems pretty odd though.

Comment: Ok, I tried with `response_type=id_token+code`. With the code I grabbed the tokens from the token endpoint which gave me the access_token, refresh_token and id_token. Both `access_token` and `id_token` are lacking the role claims again. :(

Comment: Could you add how you have defined your roles in the question? A part of the manifest for example.

Comment: Sure, updated my question.

Comment: Did you try using the scope parameter within the Authorization Request and adding "appRoles"?

Comment: I just tried it out, the roles do still not appear in any of the tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can also reproduce the issue. Not sure this a bug or by design and I found this issue only occur when we acquire the token for the app self. For example, if we replace the resource with Azure AD Graph, the role claims could issued in the id_token successfully.

As a workaround for this issue, I suggest that you acquire the id_token in the first request. And then you can acquire the access token in the iframe using adal library without user interaction since the users already sign-in.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. The problem is that - yes, I would get the roles with the id_token - but they still do not come with the access_token, even when acquiring it separately.

Comment: AFAIK, this kind of `roles` claim will not issue into access_token. The `roles` only issued issued in the access token when we request the access token using the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) which contains the permission which require admin consent.

Comment: The client-credentials flow is not user specific, as far as I can see. So how can there be roles of a specific user inside that access_token?

Comment: At present, there is no way to issue such claims in the access token. If you were developing web API, you may using the id_token instead of access token for the authentication as a workaround.

Comment: Microsoft discourages using authentication tokens for authorization

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT Using ID tokens instead of access tokens to access the API is a bad practice. Auth0 has a great documentation and explanation why:
https://auth0.com/docs/tokens
"Do not use ID tokens to gain access to an API."

Answer (score 0):

To get the "roles" claim in the access token to authorize the user requests in your back-end, follow the steps in this guide:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-tutorial/blob/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api/README.md

You will register 2 apps, one for the client (browser) and one for the server (API).

Then the most important thing after completing the steps in the guide:

Go to your server app registration "manifest" > remove "emit_as_roles" from the "optional_claims.access_token" object:

[image]

Now the roles claim will appears in the access_token